# Phonegap/Cordova - on("click") not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I'm creating a phonegap app.
This code is going to get by a json, the content on de database. Then I want to insert in the database the vote with the device.uuid. The problem is that the on("click") or on("touchstart") is not firing, not even in the alert(). Please help!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "http://filmpix.esy.es/json.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var id = field.id;
                $('.music-box').append("<button class='btn btn-default insert' value='" + id + "'>Votar</button>");
            });
        });

         $(".insert").on("touchstart", function() {
            alert("asdasd");
            var music_id = $(this).val();
            var dataString = "music_id=" + music_id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://filmpix.esy.es/insert.php",
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#insert").val('A votar...');
                    confirm("Tens a certeza que queres votar nesta musica?");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == "success") {
                        alert("inserted");
                        $("#insert").val('Votado');
                    } else if (data == "error") {
                        alert("Não foi possível votar");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there one button that has a certain ID (#insert) or are there several buttons with certain classnames? Then you want to write this: $(".insert").on(....) instead.

Comment: Yes... I've tried that before... and didn't work :( I just edit my question...

Comment: You can also use touchend-event, applying click listener directly with those buttons or checking elements that might lie upon those buttons and prevent therefore "touch"-events to be fired. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The return false statement should come after the function's "}" on your touch event.